# Login in to a web-based application using the "click" on VBS

Tags: vbscript, double-click

Our company uses a browser-based program for business operations. My goal is to be able to log into this system automatically.  The problem in front of me now is to be able to do click on one button using VBSript,

This is the code I have so far that take me to the point where I'm positioned over the button:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

call WshShell.Run("http://timeclock/portal/welcome.htm", 1, false)

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

WScript.Sleep 2000

WshShell.SendKeys "username"

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "password"

WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

WScript.Sleep 2000

WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

WScript.Sleep 4000

WshShell.SendKeys "EmployeeNumber"

WScript.Sleep 1000

WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
```

Comment: Just saving the password in the browser is not enough?

Comment: No, I need to do click on the button name "Punch In" or "punch Out"